# Module seemingly reimported in memoized Python function

Tags: python, performance, python-import, memoization, textblob

I'm writing a Python command line utility that involves converting a string into a [TextBlob](http://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/), which is part of a natural language processing module. Importing the module is very slow, ~300 ms on my system. For speediness, I created a memoized function that converts text to a TextBlob only the first time the function is called. Importantly, if I run my script over the same text twice, I want to avoid reimporting TextBlob and recomputing the blob, instead pulling it from the cache. That's all done and works fine, except, for some reason, the function is still very slow. In fact, it's as slow as it was before. I think this must be because the module is getting reimported even though the function is memoized and the import statement happens inside the memoized function.

The goal here is to fix the following code so that the memoized runs are as speedy as they ought to be, given that the result does not need to be recomputed.

Here's a minimal example of the core code:

```
@memoize
def make_blob(text):
     import textblob
     return textblob.TextBlob(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_blob("hello")
```

And here's the memoization decorator:

```
import os
import shelve
import functools
import inspect


def memoize(f):
    """Cache results of computations on disk in a directory called 'cache'."""
    path_of_this_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    cache_dirname = os.path.join(path_of_this_file, "cache")

    if not os.path.isdir(cache_dirname):
        os.mkdir(cache_dirname)

    cache_filename = f.__module__ + "." + f.__name__
    cachepath = os.path.join(cache_dirname, cache_filename)

    try:
        cache = shelve.open(cachepath, protocol=2)
    except:
        print 'Could not open cache file %s, maybe name collision' % cachepath
        cache = None

    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        argdict = {}

        # handle instance methods
        if hasattr(f, '__self__'):
            args = args[1:]

        tempargdict = inspect.getcallargs(f, *args, **kwargs)

        for k, v in tempargdict.iteritems():
            argdict[k] = v

        key = str(hash(frozenset(argdict.items())))

        try:
            return cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            value = f(*args, **kwargs)
            cache[key] = value
            cache.sync()
            return value
        except TypeError:
            call_to = f.__module__ + '.' + f.__name__
            print ['Warning: could not disk cache call to ',
                   '%s; it probably has unhashable args'] % (call_to)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped
```

And here's a demonstration that the memoization doesn't currently save any time:

```
❯ time python test.py
python test.py  0.33s user 0.11s system 100% cpu 0.437 total

~/Desktop
❯ time python test.py
python test.py  0.33s user 0.11s system 100% cpu 0.436 total
```

This is happening even though the function is correctly being memoized (print statements put inside the memoized function only give output the first time the script is run).

I've put everything together into a GitHub [Gist](https://gist.github.com/suchow/e75d4efdb5c86dd18ed6) in case it's helpful.

Comment: Can you change how your script runs to amortize the import time cost over multiple conversions? Is it just the importing that's slow or the conversion?

Comment: Python will only import the module once, memoization doesn't change anything.

Comment: @NickT, It's the import that's slow.

Comment: @stranac, do you mean to say that the module is only imported once EVER, or once each time you run the script? Because I am running the script twice here.

Comment: Once whenever you run the script. I didn't notice you were trying to save the cache using shelve.

Comment: @JWS Is that 300ms startup time really so important? If you only call your script every now and then 300ms doesn't sound like a big problem. If you call it often you could let it idle in background avoiding the startup time when it's needed.

Comment: @syntonym, it's critical — I need the entire program to run it at most that amount of time, so long imports will kill me. I see now that importing TextBlob is slow because it depends on NLTK. So I think my answer is to fork NLTK and create a version that does lazy importing or something like that. I'm not familiar with creating scripts that idle in the background, but that sounds like it could work for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

What about a different approach:

```
import pickle

CACHE_FILE = 'cache.pkl'

try:
    with open(CACHE_FILE) as pkl:
        obj = pickle.load(pkl)
except:
    import slowmodule
    obj = "something"
    with open(CACHE_FILE, 'w') as pkl:
        pickle.dump(obj, pkl)

print obj
```

Here we cache the *object*, not the module.  Note that this **will not** give you any savings if the object your caching requires `slowmodule`.  So in the above example you would see savings, since `"something"` is a string and doesn't require the `slowmodule` module to understand it.  But if you did something like

```
obj = slowmodule.Foo("bar")
```

The unpickling process would automatically import slowmodule, negating any benefit of caching.

So if you can manipulate `textblob.TextBlob(text)` into something that, when unpickled doesn't require the textblob module, then you'll see savings using this approach.